# How do I deploy a sveltekit app to a dfinity container?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, dfinity

Difinity is a blockchain container. I need a rock solid example on how to deploy a standard sveltekit app to it.

Their web page doesn’t cover sveltekit https://dfinity.org/svelte/

Here is my dfx.json file:

```
{
    "canisters": {
        "assets": {
            "dependencies": [],
            "frontend": {
                "entrypoint": "build/index.html"
            },
            "source": ["build"],
            "type": "assets"
        }
    },
    "defaults": {
        "build": {
            "output": "canisters",
            "packtool": ""
        }
    },
    "dfx": "0.9.3",
    "networks": {
        "local": {
            "bind": "127.0.0.1:8000",
            "type": "ephemeral"
        },
        "ic": {
            "providers": ["https://mainnet.dfinity.network"],
            "type": "persistent"
        }
    },
    "version": 1
}
```

The command `npm run build` will build a static version of my sveltekit app in `./build`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed the issue by adding some polyfills:

```
import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill';

....



        vite: {
            optimizeDeps: {
                esbuildOptions: {
                    // Node.js global to browser globalThis
                    define: {
                        global: 'globalThis'
                    },
                    // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
                    plugins: [
                        NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
                            buffer: true,
                            global: true,
                            process: true,
                            url: true,
                            assert: true,
                            crypto: true,
                            http: true,
                            https: true,
                            os: true,
                            stream: true
                        })
                    ]
                }
            },
...
}
```

in svelte.config.js

Answer (score 0):

The error during deployment may be due to a problem with the dfx version. Projects made with older versions of dfx may not be compatible with newer versions of dfx.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).